# Better visualization on Buckets in R

Tags: r, r-markdown

do you have any ideas on how to get a better visualization in the Buckets output? Because I'm going to put this report into PDF using Rmarkdown.

```
> EZ_liftChart(predicted=dataL_V$probVal, actual=dataL_V$Bound_Count,
+              order=1,
+              weightp=c(1),
+              weighta=c(1),
+              weightb=c(1),
+              n.buckets= 10,
+              edgy=2,
+              size=1,
+              bind=1)
```

And this is the output of the buckets.

```
bucket [,1]      
    1  -0.8125594
    2  -0.7590050
    3  -0.7189301
    4  -0.7188391
    5  -0.5047816
    6  -0.3439579
    7  -0.4376782
    8  -0.1300217
    9   0.9145718
    10  2.1844290
    11  4.8374356
```

I want the output to be a better table visualization. How can I use the kable or stargazer in Rmarkdown for this? Or are there any other functions that could improve the output like changing the column header name of the 2nd column. Thanks.

Comment: You want to visualize bucket as table? Do you want to print only first or other columns as well?

Comment: Yes, I want to visualize bucket as table. And I need to print both columns.

Comment: But I only see 1 column, could you please provide the other(s)?

Comment: Actually it's the bucket and [,1]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want. I suppose something like the table below?

[image]

This table can be produced with pander library:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(pander)
x=matrix(c(-0.8125594,-0.7590050,-0.7189301,-0.7188391,-0.5047816,-0.3439579,-0.4376782,-0.1300217,0.9145718,2.1844290,4.8374356),ncol=1)
bucket=c(1:11)

df=data.frame(Variable1=bucket,Variable2=x)

pander(df,row.names=F,caption="Bucket Table",keep.line.breaks = TRUE)
```
````

Hope this helps